# Why does Firefox allow images to be dragged but not dropped?

Tags: firefox, user-interface, drag-and-drop

If you browse a web page through Firefox, any image on the page can be dragged anywhere on the screen—but you can't drop it. Other browsers such as IE or Chrome do not allow dragging images.

Is this a issue? Why does Firefox allow dragging?

Comment: When I try to drop on mspaint or word.doc, it doesn't work

Comment: Word drops the URL if the image is a link. Paint doesn't work.

Comment: FWIW, Chrome (at least 5-dev and 6-dev versions) does allow image dragging.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can drag the image (like your favorite unicorn picture, I assume) to an explorer window and it will be saved there.

Comment: Also, you can drag an image from an explorer to the browser, and it will be displayed there. So actually it *does* support drop.

Comment: So, it can be dragged only on  "explorer window"?!

Comment: No. When he said Explorer Window, he actually meant any place on your computer showing files (My Computer, Desktop), I'm sure there's more, I just cant think of them right now.

Comment: @LittleBoy mspaint and word failing to accept an image dragged from firefox is the fault of the receiving programs. there are programs that understand it and accept the images appropriately — explorer is one such program — so firefox does allow drag and drop, it's the other programs that don't understand firefox's drop.

Answer (score 5):

It does allow you to drop. Drop to explorer/desktop and it pastes the picture, drop to a input field or the address bar and it drops the image URL.

Answer (score 0):

html does not support dragging/dropping. RIA's and some AJAX/javascript pages may allow dragging of images ... e.g a shopping cart.

Answer (score -2):

You can disable this in the firefox configuration.

http://www.google.com/search?q=firefox+image+drag